# Insert data to sqlite from json array - UWP

Tags: json, sqlite, uwp

I have stored json array values to a class and deserializing it using below code. How can I insert that json data to sqlite?

```
[{"ID":1,"name":"Shyam","class":"a"},{"ID":2,"name":"Bran","class":"b"}]

 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 using SQLitePCL;

 var StudentJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StudentClass>>(StudentJSON);
 using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\Student_DB.sqlite"))
                {
                    using (var statement = connection.Prepare(@"INSERT INTO Student (ID,name,class)
                                VALUES(?, ?,?);"))
                    {
                        // Inserts data.
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'SQLite.Net' you can insert data into sqlite table as,

```
// Insert the new student record in the Student table.  

string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "StudentDb.sqlite");

public void Insert(Student std)  
{  
    using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), dbPath))  
    {  
         conn.RunInTransaction(() =>  
          {  
              conn.Insert(std);  
           });  
    }  
}
```

Comment: shows an  error : SQLite.Net.NotNullConstraintViolationException: 'NOT NULL constraint failed: Student.ID'

Comment: It seems that you may forget to set the Student.ID field (which is not allowed to be NULL)